How to get a ContactItem with an Exchange formatted X509 email address?
I'd like to get an Outlook ContactItem using Exchange formatted X509 email address (a string). Is it possible or not?

Is X509 address one of the contact addresses? Do you see it on the contact in MFCMAPI or OutlookSpy (click IMessage)?

It's one of the contact addresses. Unfortunately, I don't use OutlookSpy.

Try MFCMAPI then.
